# C++ Include Guard Weird Behaviour?

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm working on my **SDL** game project using **Ubuntu**.
I've created a header ( declaration ) and its cpp file ( definition ).
And something started bugging me, please shed some light.

## What Works & What I Have :

( All 3 files are under the same folder )

movement.h:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
class Movement{ ...... };`
```

movement.cpp:

```
    #include <SDL2/SDL.h>
    #include "movement.h"
    // Every Definition
```

main.cpp:

```
    #include <SDL2/SDL.h>
    #include "movement.h"
    ...... // contents
```

Compile:

```
$ g++ main.cpp movement.cpp movement.h -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image
```

## What DOESN'T Work( with include guard ):

( I only changed movement.cpp, the rest stays the same )

movement.cpp:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#ifndef MOVEMENT_H
#define MOVEMENT_H
...... // contents
#endif
```

Error: Compiler complains that it can't recognize anything from movement.h
For example:

```
......
movement.cpp: At global scope:
movement.cpp:73:6: error: ‘Movement’ has not been declared
......
```

## My Questions:

1) **Why my include guard ( in `movement.cpp` ) doesn't work ?**

    I supposed it would include "movement.h" ( when there isn't one already ).

*Using include guard for `<SDL2/SDL.h>` doesn't work either( the compiler gives "not been declared" error ). The code looks like this:

```
#ifndef SDL2_SDL_H
#define SDL2_SDL_H
......
#endif
```

2) **Why `<SDL2/SDL.h>` doesn't need an include guard ?**

    Apparently there's one included in `movement.h` and another in `main.cpp`.
     Shouldn't there be a **double inclusion** error ?

Comment: The include guards need to go in the *header*. In the `.h` file, not the `.cpp` file.

Comment: The [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) or [`#pragma once`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once) is to prevent header files to be included multiple times in a single [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) (i.e. when there are multiple `#include` of the same header file). It must be part of the *header file itself*.

Comment: To be abundantly clear: Adding an include guard _does not automatically include that file_. It seems like you expect that `#ifndef MOVEMENT_H
#define MOVEMENT_H` somehow includes `movement.h` - it does not.

Comment: You don't compile header files `g++ main.cpp movement.cpp -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image` not `g++ main.cpp movement.cpp movement.h -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> movement.h:
>
> ```
> #include <SDL2/SDL.h>
> class Movement{ ...... };
> ```

Headers may be included into multiple files. You should use a header guard, which seems to be missing from this header.

---

> 1) Why my include guard ( in movement.cpp ) doesn't work ?
>
> movement.cpp:
>
> ```
> #include <SDL2/SDL.h>
> #ifndef MOVEMENT_H
> #define MOVEMENT_H
> ```

Source files should never be *included* into other files, so you shouldn't need an *include* guard.

---

> Compile:
>
> ```
> $ g++ main.cpp movement.cpp movement.h -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image
>                             ^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

Header files don't need to be compiled.

---

> 2) Why `<SDL2/SDL.h>` doesn't need an include guard ?

[SDL2/SDL.h](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/davidsiaw/SDL2/master/include/SDL.h) does have an include guard:

> ```
> #ifndef SDL_h_
> #define SDL_h_
> ```

---

> Apparently there's one included in movement.h and another in main.cpp. Shouldn't there be a double inclusion error ?

No. The header guard removes the latter inclusion. That is what header guard is for.

P.S. Header guard is only required if the header has definitions. A header which only has declarations doesn't need to have a guard. However, it's easier to simply use a header guard in all headers than to try to figure out which of the headers they are not needed for.